# Magento upgrade from 2.2.3 -> 2.3 error in module-configurable-product

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2.3, magento2.3, setup-upgrade

Upgrading M2 from 2.2.3 to 2.3 gives me the following error during the `magento setup:upgrade` process:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, boolean given in /vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateManufacturerAttribute.php:55
```

`/vendor/magento/module-eav/Setup/EavSetup.php::getAttribute` can return false - which it does in my case:

`$eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'manufacturer', 'apply_to')` returns `bool(false)`

See `vendor/magento/module-eav/Setup/EavSetup.php` line 1163:

```
        if ($field !== null) {
            return isset($row[$field]) ? $row[$field] : false;
        }
```

The update script `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateManufacturerAttribute.php` in Line 55 does not check for booleans.

```
        $relatedProductTypes = explode(
            ',',
            $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'manufacturer', 'apply_to')
        );
```

How do I fix this error?

Simply skipping this by exiting if the value is false gives me another error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3955 ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentionned in this [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19739#issuecomment-447878311) on the M2 github

> Search in the database in table eav_attribute for attribute manufacturer and copy the ID. With this id search in catalog_eav_attribute. Now enter the following in column apply_to
>
> simple, virtual, bundle, downloadable, configurable
>
> Now setup:upgrade is working.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I didn't see that issue. It fixed it.

Comment: Thanks!! it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

We also encountered this problem when we upgraded from 2.2.5 to 2.3. The problem we had was the manufacturer eav_attribute did not exist at all. We followed this [Magento Github Issue #19739](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19739) and inserted an eav_attribute record with the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO eav_attribute (entity_type_id, attribute_code, backend_type, frontend_input, frontend_label, frontend_class, is_required, is_user_defined, is_unique) VALUES ((SELECT entity_type_id from eav_entity_type where entity_type_code='catalog_product'), 'manufacturer', 'varchar', 'text', 'Manufacturer', 'validate-length maximum-length-255', 0, 0, 0);
```

After confirming the manufacturer record is in place, insert a record in the catalog_eav_attribute table using the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_eav_attribute (attribute_id, is_global, is_visible, is_searchable, is_filterable, is_comparable, is_visible_on_front, is_html_allowed_on_front, is_used_for_price_rules, is_filterable_in_search, used_in_product_listing, used_for_sort_by, apply_to, is_visible_in_advanced_search, position, is_wysiwyg_enabled, is_used_for_promo_rules, is_required_in_admin_store, is_used_in_grid, is_visible_in_grid, is_filterable_in_grid, search_weight, additional_data) VALUES ((SELECT attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='manufacturer'), 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, "simple, virtual, bundle, downloadable, configurable", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL);
```

We also got caught with some modules had their schema updated and not data as the setup:upgrade aborted midway through. We had to manually update the schema version aligned with the data version in setup_module table to ensure a clean redeploy.

Interesting note, in our development instances where the sample data are part of the required composer package, the manufacturer eav attribute exist and it's an int type with a select frontend input.

Hope that helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Precisely, to fix the error

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, boolean given in vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateManufacturerAttribute.php:55

You can simply execute the below SQL:

```
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute SET apply_to = 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable' WHERE attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'manufacturer' AND entity_type_id = 4
)
```

**Note**: `apply_to` attribute can be guessed from the exception trace during `setup:upgrade`